# C++ - Advancing a pointer passed as an argument

Tags: c++, function

I am having trouble advancing a pointer passed in as an argument. The ideas is that the function will read the value at the pointer and advance the pointer. Do I need to pass it in by reference? Is it even possible to pass a pointer by reference?

```
int32 File::readDWORD(char* offset)
{
    int32 value;
    memcpy(&value, offset, sizeof(int32));
    offset += sizeof(int32);
    return value;
}
```

The function reads the value and advances the local pointer but I want it to advance the one passed in.

Comment: Why `sizeof(uint32)` and not `sizeof(int32)` (or better, `sizeof(value)`)?

Comment: Yes it is possible, and yes that's what you must do here.

Answer (score 3):

You can either pass your pointer by reference, or pass a pointer to pointer (a handle). Both solutions will allow you to modify the *pointer's value*, so the location it's pointing into.

Note however, that usually you shouldn't use "raw" pointers in C++. Memory operations that you've presented can be replaced with more high level language constructs; the one I could think of is encapsulating your File class better, in a way possibly similar to streams.

This can lead to another question - why don't you just use `std::fstream`?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

```
int32 WLD::readDWORD(const char*&offset)
{
    int32 value;
    memcpy(&value, offset, sizeof(int32));
    offset += sizeof(int32);
    return value;
}

char*pter = initial;
WLD::readDWORD(pter);
assert(pter == initial+sizeof(int32));
```

Here `offset` is a reference to a `const char*`. Thus, while you can change the pointer you cannot change what it is pointing to. This is exactly what you want in this case.

you shouldn't change the behaviour by "requesting to change the behaviour to pass by reference" (via compiler options). That makes your code non-portable and non-standard and non-human-readable (except by those who know ...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and yes. Unless you specifically request pass-by-reference all parameters (pointers included) are passed by value meaning that altering the value of the parameter won't alter the state of any variable that might have been used as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it by reference

```
int32 File::readDWORD(char* & offset)
{
     [...]
     offset += sizeof(uint32);
     [...]
}
```